# XML Tag formatting

Tags: java, xml, xsd, apache-camel

I am trying to print map and print XML in camel exchange. But I am getting an extra xml tag for each class which are declared as list. Here is the Pojo classes which I created.

Student :

```
public class Student {

  @XmlElement
  private List<StudentRecord> studentRecord;


}
```

Student Record

```
public class StudentRecord {

  @XmlElement
  private String name;


  @XmlElement
  private int age;


  @XmlElement
  private String department;


}
```

In my processor class I am setting values as

```
Student student = new Student();
List<StudentRecord> studentlist = new ArrayList<StudentRecord>();
StudentRecord srd = new StudentRecord();
srd.setName(studentname);
srd.setAge(studentage);
srd.setDepartment(studentDepartment);
studentlist.add(srd);
student.setStudentRecord(studentlist);
```

I am using XML mapper to convert to xml format and send it using

```
exchange.getIN().setBody(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(student));
```

I got below output.

```
<Student>
  <StudentRecord>
    <StudentRecord>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <age>22</age>
        <Department>Computer Science</Department>
    </StudentRecord>
   </StudentRecord>
</Student>
```

Actual output I need:

```
<Student>
    <StudentRecord>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <age>22</age>
        <Department>Computer Science</Department>
    </StudentRecord>
</Student>
```

I am not able to find where I am going wrong. Should I change pojo's or should I change my code where I am setting values.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please fix your entity classes code, now both classes are called `Student`. Also, in your `Student` definition (the upper one) you use `List<StudentRecords>` but in the output you need there's no root element for array. Or is it your goal to have StudentRecords directly in a Student class? Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: I have a list of student records in Student class

Answer (score 0):

You named your list element `studentRecord`. Therefore you have **two nested elements with the same name**. The outer is the list element, the inner is the container element of the `StudentRecord` class.

If the XML would be as you want, **you would render the list invisible**. The example output with just one student could be the list with 1 element. But it could also be a Student class that contains a single student.